# opencv: cv2.goodFeaturesToTrack not working

Tags: python, opencv

I was trying to run a code from a standard tutorial on opencv.
Link - http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_shi_tomasi/py_shi_tomasi.html#shi-tomasi

But I every time I try to compile it I get this error-

> File "gft.py", line 8, in 
>       corners = cv2.goodFeaturesToTrack(gray,25,0.01,10) cv2.error: /build/opencv-SviWsf/opencv-2.4.9.1+dfsg/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp:236:
>   error: (-215) step[dims-1] == (size_t)CV_ELEM_SIZE(flags) in function
>   create

Can somebody suggest a solution please.

Comment: Can you provide the sample code? Are you sure that the image is loaded correctly?

Comment: @Miki , I have tried a lot of images.

Comment: @ Miki `import numpy as np<br/>
import cv2 <br/>
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt <br/>

img = cv2.imread('chess-board.jpg') <br/>
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) <br/>

corners = cv2.goodFeaturesToTrack(gray,25,0.01,10) <br/>
corners = np.int0(corners) <br />

for i in corners: <br/>
    x,y = i.ravel() <br/>
    cv2.circle(img,(x,y),3,255,-1) <br/>

plt.imshow(img),plt.show()`